# Vizualise different projections of a vector using QGIS

Tags: qgis, reprojection-mathematics

How to vizualise different map projection for a vector layer at once with QGIS,  then export the two forms as Geographic WGS84

e.g. I have a shapefile for Europe, how to vizualise it in CRS Lambert Azimutha Equal Area, Lambert Conic Conformal, and GCS WGS84 at once, to see the shifting and etc... then export them all as WGS84

Please see [image]

PS: I know how to reproject layer and save them in any CRS or GCS

Comment: You could set the projection of the layers without changing the coordinates have them shown on the same map. But I doubt it will work as the countries won't have the same center and height/width, so the *Europes* will be far apart from each other. I think you would be better off using an image editor to fake-lay them on top of each other after you exported them individually.

Answer (score 4):

Disable the CRS for the project. Without a project CRS, QGIS will not do any reprojection at all and treat all coordinates as pure numbers without any geographic meaning.

Go to project -> properties -> CRS and enable "No projection (or unknown/non-Earth projection)".